# Как предотвратить ошибочное экранирование данных при запросе?

Tags: codeigniter, mysql

```
$results =  $this->db
->select('birthday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, birthday, "'.date('Y-09-01').'") as age, groups.name')
->where('TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, birthday, "'.date('Y-09-01').'")>=78')
->join('groups', 'groups.id = m.group', 'inner')
->get('main m', 15, $page)
->result();
```

затем он генерит мне правильный запрос:

```
SELECT `birthday`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `birthday`, `"2012-09-01")` as age, `groups`.`name` FROM (`main` m) INNER JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`id` = `m`.`group` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, birthday, "2012-09-01")>=78 LIMIT 15
```

Вроде как правильный, но посмотрите на вот этот вот бред:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `birthday`, `"2012-09-01")` as age,
```

CodeIgniter по левому поставил последние кавычки в `select`
Народ, че делать?

Comment: C CI особо не знаком, но раз он сам кавычки выставляет, то может ему отдавать строки без кавычек, или попробовать не двойные, а одинарные

Comment: мысль хорошо, пробывал и так и так а он в конце все равно одну левую кавычку ставит, а функцию нельзя в кавычки.
мб можно вырубить у него эту фичу, кавычки расставлять?

Answer (score 3):

[Согласно документации](http://www.code-igniter.ru/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

> `$this->db->select()` принимает второй необязательный параметр.
>   Если  вы установите его в `FALSE`, то CodeIgniter не будет пытаться
>   обезопасить имена полей или таблиц с помощью одинарных кавычек.
>   Это удобно, если вам нужно создать вложенный оператор `select`.

Ваш исправленный код:

```
$results =  $this->db
->select(
    'birthday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, birthday, "'.date('Y-09-01').'") as age, groups.name',
    false
)
->where('TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, birthday, "'.date('Y-09-01').'")>=78')
->join('groups', 'groups.id = m.group', 'inner')
->get('main m', 15, $page)
->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->select("birthday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, birthday, ".date('Y-09-01').") as age, groups.name")
```

Попробуй так написать.

Comment: нее, то ковычяка закрывает строку переданную в where, смотри внимательнее

Comment: обновил ответ ты не туда смотришь.

Comment: ребят.
1) Если в TIMESTAMPDIFF передать параметр без кавычек то он не отработает.
2) Если понадеется на игнайтер, на то что кавычки поставит он то зря, он сволота ставит так:
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, `birthday`, `2012-09-01)/12` as age

Comment: попробуй так, может он не воспринимает **date('**

Comment: да не, это просто CI задница полная

Answer (score -1):

```
$results =  $this->db
->select('birthday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, birthday, **"**'.date('Y-09-01').'**"**)
```

Убрать кавычки тут

Comment: не помогает, он в любом случае ставит кавычку в конце функции

Answer (score -2):

Возьми дату еще в скобки `("2012-09-01")`